# For loop 3 digit formatting not working as expected

Tags: batch

I'm trying to make a for loop to make echo.

Example:

```
for /l in (1,1,12) do (set valt=00%g & echo %valt%)
```

I'm waiting for :

> 001 002 003 etc...

But it's returned me twelve times the value 0012.

Can you tell me why the loop isn't working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One output per line:

```
> set "_valt=0" & for /l %g in (1,1,12)do @call set "_valt=00%~g" & cmd /v /c echo\!_valt:~-3!
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
```

---

All outputs on the same line:

```
> set "_valt=0" & for /l %g in (1,1,12)do @call set "_valt=00%~g" & cmd /v /c <nul set /p "=!_valt:~-3!"
001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 011 012
```

You need the value of the expanded variable at runtime on the same line:

> *With loop commands like FOR, compound or bracketed expressions,*
> *Delayed Expansion will allow you to always read the current value of the variable.*
> *You can write new variable values with or without Delayed Expansion.*
>
> *Without delayed expansion you can swap the value of two variables in one line:*
> ***`Set "var1=%var2%" & set "var2=%var1%"`***
>
> *When Delayed Expansion is in effect, variables can be immediately read using !variable_name!*
> *You can set two variables to the same thing in one line:*
> ***[`Set "var3=April" & set "var4=!var3!"`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)***

---

> **`CMD.exe /?`**
> *Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.*
>
> *Syntax*
> *CMD [charset] [options]*
>
> *CMD [charset] [options] [/C Command]*
>
> *Options*
> */C     Run Command and then terminate*
> */V:ON Enable delayed environment variable expansion*
> *this allows a FOR loop to specify !variable! instead of   %variable%*
> ***[`expanding the variable at execution time instead of at input time.`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)***